# Unable to deploy ML.net, "missing" FastTreeNative.dll

Tags: c#, windows-server, ml.net

I have some C# code (VS2017, .Net 4.71) that uses the Microsoft ML.net library (via nuget). It works fine on my own Windows 10 development machine, but when I deploy it to a production server, I get the exception

> (Inner Exception #0) System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FastTreeNative': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The server is Windows Server 2016 x64, with .Net 4.71 installed, and the code is built to target x64. `FastTreeNative.dll` is in the executable path. Following [a related issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/93), I've moved from `packages.config` to a PackageReference - all to no avail. What can I do to track down why this DLL isn't being loaded?

Comment: Is the `FastTreeNative.dll` also a x64 binary, or is it targeting x86?

Comment: It's x64 native, but I've managed to fix it - see below. I wonder if there's a name for the phenomenon where posting a question to SO stimulates your own brain to solve the problem you've been struggling with for days a few minutes later :)

Comment: @KenD for naming this phenomenon `Rubber Duck Debugging` sounds close enough. http://blog.tdwright.co.uk/2017/09/25/rubber-duck-debugging-with-stackoverflow/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `dumpbin` to look at the dependencies of `FastTreeNative.dll`

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file FastTreeNative.dll

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
```

VCRUNTIME140 is the Visual Studio C++ Redistributable. Once quick [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and install later, the problem is solved!

Comment: [For the future references] Same error was happening to me having two projects:

1) A Core library .NET Standard 2.0 implementing ML.
2) WCF Application .NET Framework 4.7 needing ML as reference.

I've just changed the 'Platform Target' (at Properties > Build) from 'Any CPU' to 'x64' in all the projects using the Core library. Error was gone.